# Session expiration date are fixed to 1969

Tags: session, cookies, cache-expiration

I'm working on a website, and i found that some cookie expiration date are fixed to 1969.

My question is why?

[image]

Are these cookies persistent or null?

PS. I'm running Magento 1.9

Comment: You may be facing [this issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7627)

Answer (score 0):

try this one after the session_start function:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 30*60); 
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60);
```

PHPSESSID appears to be persistent